# Hive Partition number of reducers

Tags: hive, partitioning, reducers

Can you clarify on the below -

1. How does the number of mappers and reducers get set during partitioing?
2. I have 6 reducers and 2 partitions  and each partition has only file in it (total 2 files). So, if there are 6 reducers, they are supposed to give   6 files correct....Then how is it possible to give only 2 output files (partitions).?

Thanks,
Arun